# How to save the output to txt file?

Tags: python

When I got the number of how many times of the words, I wanted to save the output to a `txt` file. But when I used the following code, only `counts` appeared in the output file. Anyone knows the problem here?
Thank you very much!

My code: (part)

```
d = c.split() # make a string into a list of words
#print d
counts = Counter(d) # count the words 
print(counts)

import sys
sys.stdout = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/out.txt", "w")
print 'counts'
```

Comment: Don't you want to do `print 'counts ', counts`  instead?

Comment: Is there something missing in existing answers that doesn't solve your problem? If not, could you please pick the one that works for you as selected one, so future people will be able to find the answer they need quickly?

Comment: sure. they all work for me very well. I'll pick one. Sorry:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

c = "When I got the number of how many times of the words"
d = c.split() # make a string into a list of words
counts = Counter(d) # count the words 
sys.stdout = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/out.txt", "w")
print(str(len(d)) + ' words') #this shows the number of total words 
for i in counts:
    print(str(i), str(counts[i]) + ' counts')
```

With te result in **out.txt**

```
12 words
When 1 counts
got 1 counts
many 1 counts
times 1 counts
the 2 counts
words 1 counts
I 1 counts
number 1 counts
how 1 counts
of 2 counts
```

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, may I ask how to count how many (different) words in the output? For example, In this case, I have 10 words(When I got the number of how many times words).

Comment: I've added a line of code which writes in `out.txt` the total number of words.

Answer (score 3):

Working as intended as python is a dynamic language and everything as it was during runtime. So in order to capture everything you will have to redirect your stdout at the begging of your script.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/out.txt", "w")
d = c.split() # make a string into a list of words
#print d
counts = Counter(d) # count the words 
print(counts)

print 'counts'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
d = c.split() # make a string into a list of words
#print d
counts = Counter(d) # count the words 
sys.stdout = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/out.txt", "w")
print(counts)
print 'counts'
```

`print` prints to stdout. You need to redirrect stdout to the file before printing the number of counts.

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly nicer option, would be to use some of the newer Python features:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open(r'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\out.txt', 'w') as f:
    d = c.split() # make a string into a list of words
    #print(d, file=f)
    counts = Counter(d) # count the words 
    print(counts, file=f)

    print('counts', file=f)
```

Alternatively, you could use the logging module:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename=r'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\out.txt'))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


wordlist = c.split()
logger.debug('Wordlist: %s', wordlist)

logger.debug('Counting words..')
counts = Counter(wordlist)
logger.debug('Counts: %s', counts)
```

As it appears you're on Windows, you can use the incredibly useful [baretail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) application to watch your log as your program executes.